# how to select single item in listbox row

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox, click, row

I want to display 3 images in a row in an `ListBox`. I can't use `WrapPanel` because it will lose virtualization. So I use `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

In my `ListBoxItem` template, I have 3 images in a horizontal `StackPanel`. I want to allow user to click on a single image, but `ListBox`'s default behavior only allows to click a whole `ListBoxItem`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want selection on the full row, you should switch to an `ItemsControl` instead of a `ListBox`.

To allow selection of images on every row set the `ItemTemplate` of this `ItemsControl` to a ListBox, binded to a collection of images.

Here is some sample code that should work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--THe ItemTemplate is a ListBox of Images-->
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Img}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!--This is required to have the scroll-->
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Border>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```